# How to flush the print buffer in Kojo IDE (Scala) to the output pane?

Tags: java, scala, ide

In this wonderful IDE built on Scala/Java, my child can easily create simple games. Here, we have a car reacting to his keyboard events as follows:

```
// car is a PicShape (PicShape.rect to be precise)
car.react { self => 
    if (isKeyPressed(Kc.VK_P)) {
        println("Pausing")
        Console.out.flush() // this is supposed to work in Java and Scala, I think. But it doesn't in Kojo.
        Thread.sleep(3000) // wait for 3 seconds
    }
    // more code here listening to other events like turning left or right...
}
```

The trouble is that the message "Pausing" does not show up until the thread wakes up. Any ideas?

Comment: Note: PicShape.rect is obsolete. Kojo now has Picture.rectangle. So, car is defined as:
val car = Picture.rectangle(30, 100) // plus costume/animation and key/mouse handlers..
car.draw()